# Wordpress - List out tags on template files

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I list out all the tags to a template file?

I've looked at the wordpress documentation and found this..

```
<?php
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
           echo $tag->name . ' '; 
        }
    }
 ?>
```

However this doesn't output anything to my template.

Is there something that I am missing that i need to do on templates?

Comment: was is the output of `var_dump($posttags)` or have you become any error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
    $posttags  = get_terms( array(  'taxonomy' => 'post_tag') );

    if ($posttags ) {
        foreach($posttags  as $tag) {
            echo $tag->name . ' '; 
        }
    }
 ?>
```