# Wordpress - Outputting a list of tags to a template

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the best way to output a list of tag names to a template in wordpress?

I have tried to use the following without success:

```
get_tags()
get_all_tags()
```

But neither of them seem to return the tag names.

I have also read up on cloud tags? Let me know the best way you have found to output a list of tag names onto a template file in wordpress..

Comment: bizarre ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047119/wordpress-list-out-tags-on-template-files

Comment: duplicate questions of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047119/wordpress-list-out-tags-on-template-files

Comment: Thanks Vel. That solution didn't work for me however.